# How can I recover a profile picture from an author in other app?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a blog post right now and I'm new at Django. I have an avatar picture in another app(registration) and I'm trying to import and associate correctly to another app (pages). In other words, I need to recover, in the HTML, the exact avatar picture from the user who creates a post. Thanks!

models.py (registration)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):
    old_instance = Profile.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    old_instance.avatar.delete()
    return 'profiles/' + filename

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user__username']

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def ensure_profile_exists(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

models.py (pages)

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registration.models import Profile

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Título", max_length=200)                             # Titulo 
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', verbose_name="autor", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    content = RichTextField(verbose_name="Contenido")                                           # Contenido 
    order = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Orden", default=0)                           # Orden de publicacion
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Fecha de creación")         # Fecha de creacion
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Fecha de edición")              # Fecha de actualizacion


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "página"
        verbose_name_plural = "páginas"
        ordering = ['order', 'title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py (pages)

```
from .models import Page
from django.views.generic.list import ListView 
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from .forms import PageForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from registration.models import Profile

#Decoradores
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
class StaffRequiredMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(StaffRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class PageListView(ListView):
    model = Page

@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")
class PageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Page

# CRUD: 
@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class PageCreate(CreateView):
    model = Page 
    form_class = PageForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.post = form.save(commit=False)
        self.post.author =  self.request.user
        self.post.save()
        return super(PageCreate, self).form_valid(form)

@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class PageUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Page
    form_class = PageForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('pages:update', args=[self.object.id]) + '?ok'

@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class PageDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Page
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to provide the data using `get_context_data()` in the PageListView or PageDetailView. Something like:

```py
class PageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Page

   def get_context_data(**kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

       # Profile image has a url property, so in the template {{ profile_image.url }}
       profile_image = self.object.author.user.profile.avatar
       context['profile_image'] = profile_image

       return context
```

Take care: An error can be raised if `author.user.profile` does not exist. You can test for the relationship with `hasattr(author.user, "profile")`.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I'm having a error that says: TypeError at /pages/: get_context_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. I think, like you say, that error is because the 'author.user.profile' doesn't exist. I'm a little confused trying to import the avatar. Thank you anyway, I will be reading to learn more about the problem!